# How to create "private component routes" in Angular 5

Tags: angular, router

I have this structure in my project:

- The main html contains a router-outlet element and routes to Comp1 or
  Comp2.
- Comp2 contains a "ReusemainComponent" by using its selector:
  "app-reusemain".
- The ReusemainComponent contains a router-outlet
  element and routes to Reusechild1Component or Reusechild1Component.

ReusemainComponent and its 2 children are in a separate module.

That gives the following tree: ( '=>' denotes routing)

```
app.component
    =>Comp1  
    =>Comp2  
        app-reusemain (used via its selector)  
            =>Reusechild1  
            =>Reusechild2
```

I would like the reusemain component to be independent and reusable but to have internal routes reusechild1 and reusechild2.

This snippet shows that I also mean to pass a property via property binding.

```html
<div> something ...  </div>
<app-reusemain [childProperty]="parentProperty"></app-reusemain>
```

Trying to navigate to "route1" (one of the "private child routes") results in navigating to "/route1" and of course fails.

In this case, there is no continuous route from the app root down to the "child-selector" component and its own children as the "child-selector" kind of initiates its own.

I tried auxiliary routes but I guess the router did not reach the named router outlet inside the "child-selector" template.

Is it at all possible to use the angular router this way?

Link to an example: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Apm0hUmOfH7mzEfawhTNvxjrersv

Comment: Have you heard about relative routing ? You can import it with separate module containing your shared component.

Comment: I have but how does it help in this case? Can you explain a bit more. My issue is to insert a component that uses routing internally (has child components) via its selector.